# Synchrotron Radiation: relativisitic beaming and Visualization

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, relativity

Not sure if this question really belongs here, but I hope it does (at least to first order).

I'm looking into the synchrotron radiation emitted by an electron on circular path. Out of curiosity I'd like to find a 3D parameterization for the angular distribution of the radiation and plot it.
In case of a 2D representation, I understand that the distribution is described by
$$P\propto \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\left( 1 - \beta\cos\theta \right)^5}$$

Which is also easy to plot in a 2D graph and allows to show the effect of $\beta\rightarrow1$ for highly relativistic particles:
[image]

Is it possible to parametrize that in a 3D case, such that I can create a surface plot (for example pgfplots or python) to show that effect?

Hopefully I described the issue clearly enough - any support is much appreciated!